# What are the rules of a student of the three vedas mentioned in Apastambasmriti Prasna 1?

Tags: vedas, dharma-shastras, smriti, upanayanam

> Failure to be Initiated:  If his time for initiation has lapsed, a man
> should live observing the rules of a student of the three Vedas for
> one season  and then undergo initiation. For a year thereafter he
> should take a daily bath,  after which time he may receive vedic
> instruction.
>
> Apastamba Dharmasutra Prasna 1 Sutras 28-31

What are these rules that a student of the three vedas follows?

Acc. to Apastamba this is the penance for a late Upanayanam.

Comment: it's all the same rules as brahmacharya vrat.